# How to set softdeletes condition as first clause in query with laravel models?

Tags: laravel, model, query-optimization, laravel-6, soft-delete

I have a simple question. Could anyone help me please?
In laravel models, we can use `Sotfdeletes` trait. So this trait add the `whereNull('deleted_at')` sentence. It is ok. However, we have a big table and our queries are very slow.

We have `Company` model which use `SotfDeletes` trait. It has some scope methods such as `createdAtBigger`, `nameLike`, `oneOfBoard` etc.
This is the company model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

/**
 * @method static|Builder createdAtBigger(\DateTime $datetime)
 * @method static|Builder nameLike(string $name)
 * @method static|Builder oneOfBoard(array $boardIds)
 */
class Company extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function scopeCreatedAtBigger(Builder $builder, $datetime)
    {
        return $builder->where('created_at', '>', $datetime);
    }

    public function scopeNameLike(Builder $builder, $name)
    {
        return $builder->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%');
    }

    public function scopeOneOfBoard(Builder $builder, $boardIds)
    {
        return $builder->whereIn('board_id', $boardIds);
    }

    /**
     * the other methods and scopes
     * ...
     * ...
     * ...
     */
}
```

When we try to use that model with these scopes, it likes that for example:

```
$companies = Company::nameLike('XX Company')
        ->oneOfBoard([1,2,3,4])
        ->createdAtBigger('2022-02-14')
        ->get();
```

and its sql is like that:

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM company 
   WHERE name like '%XX Company%' 
     and created_at > '2022-02-14' 
     and board_id in(1,2,3,4) 
     and deleted_at=null;
```

You can see, the deleted_at clause is the last condition.
This table has mostly deleted rows.
I want to move `deleted_at` condition at the **first**.
If my sql will like that, it it will take half time than now:

But I couldn't.

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM company 
   WHERE deleted_at=null 
     and name like '%XX Company%' 
     and created_at > '2022-02-14' 
     and board_id in(1,2,3,4);
```

I don't want to use `deletedAtNotNull` scope because this model is very huge. It has lots of calls.

How can I do it? Is that any way?

PS: Thanks for @timlewis, I have an index on deleted_at column.

Comment: What SQL engine is this? MySql? PostGres? Something else? In my experience, placement/ordering of the `WHERE` statements doesn't make any difference to execution time of the query, but I don't know if that applies to all SQL engines, and you didn't indicate which one this is.

Comment: I use mysql innodb engine.

Comment: Then yeah, placing that `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` closer to the top of your query shouldn't make a difference. Have you ran this query against an `EXPLAIN ...` clause to see which part is _actually_ taking the longest? Or is it maybe something you're doing in PHP/Laravel?

Comment: But I have an index on deleted_at column. I couldn't use the board_id index because of in clause so I added an index on deleted_at. Now, query run faster.

Comment: And, I run with explain. First it examined 133432 row but with `WHERE deleted_at is null` it examined 66687 rows.